# Swashbuckle: Customize endpoint path (AspNetCore)

Tags: swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have this setup where I want to organize multiple APIs served by the same application
.
For each api I get the prefix from the subdomain and redirect it to the application server, example:

user.api.example.com/v1/profile --> api.example.com/user/v1/profile

admin.api.example.com/v1/companies --> api.example.com/admin/v1/companies

With this setup, I need to remove the path prefix ("/user", "/admin") when generating the swagger json file.

Is it possible to configure a function that will manipulate the path for each endpoint before generating the json file?

I only want to alter what goes into the swagger json file, not the actual endpoint path!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document Filters were the answers to that particular need:

```
public class PathPrefixDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var editedPaths = new OpenApiPaths();
        foreach(var kv in swaggerDoc.Paths)
        {
            var newKey = string.Join("/", kv.Key.Split('/').Skip(2));
            editedPaths.Add("/"+newKey, kv.Value);
        }
        swaggerDoc.Paths = editedPaths;
        var a = swaggerDoc.Paths;
    }
}
```